# Is there a way to use the 'AllowAnyOrigin' property on a CorsPolicy within .NET Core?

Tags: c#, .net-core, cors

I'm currently working on integrated Cors within a .Net Core app. I have previously dealt with Cors within the full .NET Framework (4.6.1) which had the ability to set the `AllowAnyOrigin` property within a given CorsPolicy.

Like mentioned before, I have written a .NET Core WebApi, which I am trying to implement Cors into. I have it reading from an AppSetting stored in my `appSettings.json`, from which it can be either three things:

- If the appsetting is set to an asterisk, then I would like to see the AllowAnyOrigin property like I have done in the full .NET framework. (This is where my problem lies.)
- If the appsetting is set to a comma seperated string, such as `https://example.com, https://test.com`, then this is applied onto the policy as needed.
- If the appsetting has been commented out or left as empty, then I am reading a list of rows from Azure Table Storage to supply a list of given origins.

Below is an example of the full .NET framework that I have dealt with before.

```
            var origins = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[KeyCorsAllowOrigin];

            switch (origins)
            {
                case null:
                    _corsPolicy.Origins.Clear();
                    foreach (var item in new StorageConfigurationManager().GetRowKeys())
                    {
                        _corsPolicy.Origins.Add("https://" + item);
                    }
                    break;
                case "*":
                    _corsPolicy.AllowAnyOrigin = true;
                    break;
                default:
                    _corsPolicy.AllowAnyOrigin = false;
                    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(origins)) AddCommaSeparatedValuesToCollection(origins, _corsPolicy.Origins);
                    break;
            }
```

I thought that I could replicate this functionality within .NET Core and the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors.Infrastructure` package, but it seems that Microsoft has restricted access to setting the property, and can only be read from.

Does anyone know of any way to set this?

I know you can build the CorsPolicy within the pipeline, which then uses the `.AllowAnyOrigin()`, but I am currently using custom Cors middleware to help with my custom policy.

Answer (score 1):

There is a great article called [Enabling CORS in ASP.NET Core](https://code-maze.com/enabling-cors-in-asp-net-core/) I'll sum the interesting part for you:

to only allow GET methods on your resource, you can use the `WithMethods` method when you define the CORS policy:

```
services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("AllowOrigin",
            builder => builder.WithOrigins("http://localhost:55294")
                              .WithMethods("GET"));
});
```

---

If you need to allow any origin to access the resource, you will use AllowAnyOrigin instead of WithOrigins:

```
services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("AllowOrigin",
        builder => builder.AllowAnyOrigin());
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply! At the moment, I'm only using `services.AddCors` when configuring my services, as it's all done via my custom middleware instead. This provides me with the policy to use instead of constructing it with a lambda in the `AddCors` or `UseCors`.

Answer (score 0):

Just as an answer to all this, and so that perhaps someone can be helped by this question. I looked at the source code for the AllowAnyOrigin method within the [CorsPolicyBuilder](https://github.com/HydAu/AspNetCors/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Cors/CorsPolicyBuilder.cs) class and saw how this was handled. I nearly had the solution, just forgot to clear the Origins list beforehand.

```
_policy.Origins.Clear();
_policy.Origins.Add(CorsConstants.AnyOrigin);
```